# Web.Config causes 500 internal server error

Tags: iis-7, web-config

This is my `web.config` file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<configuration> 

    <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

     </system.webServer>

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I'm trying to use pretty permalinks of wordpress.

But this `web.config` files causes `500 Internal Server Error`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was from the server, they have not installed `Microsoft URL Rewriting Module` correctly...

The module has been installed correctly, and then problem solved.

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi. Had same issue on Win2k12 using ASP.NET MVC, installed this http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Mahdi is correct. However, if you are unable to install the URL Rewrite module (which was the problem I had due to some signature verification problem), you can download an older version of the module from the link provided below. This ended up working for me.
Hope this helps.

https://forums.iis.net/t/1239468.aspx?URL+rewrite+installation+failing+due+to+signature+verification+failure